# h:commandButton inside composite is invoked but does not navigate to the specified page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, navigation, composite-component, commandbutton

I'm trying to learn JSF Composite component. I have created a registration form composite component and I have a problem with the attribute that invokes a method in my managed bean.

registrationComposite.xhtml (code snippet)

```
<composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="registerButton_action"
                    method-signature="java.lang.String register()"/>
 </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>

       <h:form>
         <h:commandButton type="submit"
                        action="#{cc.attrs.registerButton_action}"
                        value="#{cc.attrs.registerButton_label}" />

       </h:form>

       </composite:implementation>
```

namespace;

> xmlns:register="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/composite">

registration.xhtml

```
<register:registrationComposite
registerButton_label="Register"
                registerButton_action="#{student.register()}" />
```

Student.class (Managedbean)

```
public String register() {
    System.out.println("inside register method");
    return "success.xhtml";
}
```

When I click the register button, the student's register() method is invoked but does not navigate to the returned string("success.xhtml"). Maybe it was not returning the string value? What seems to be the problem?

Comment: problem solved. I have placed the success.xhtml in the wrong directory.

Comment: so you had an error somewhere?

Comment: there was no error or exception. its just that the "success.xhtml" is in a wrong directory.